# I tried to put the form data in my show.html page. But it not working. I am using flask_sqlalchemy. I am begginer in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to be able to get the data sent to my Flask app. I've tried accessing request.form but it is an empty string. How do you access request data?
I want to be able to get the data sent to my Flask app. I've tried accessing request.form but it is an empty string. How do you access request data?

my app.py file

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///students.sqlite3'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class students(db.Model):
    id=db.Column('student_id',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(100))
    city=db.Column(db.String(50))
    addr=db.Column(db.String(200))
    pin=db.Column(db.String(10))
def __init__(self,name,city,addr,pin):
    self.name=name
    self.city=city
    self.addr=addr
    self.pin=pin
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_all():
    return render_template('show.html',students=students.query.all())
@app.route('/new',methods=['GET','POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student=students(request.form['name'],request.form['city'],
        request.form['addr'],request.form['pin'])
        db.session.add(student)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
    return render_template('new.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**my new.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Your city"><br>
    <input type="text" name="addr" placeholder="your address"><br>
    <input type="text" name="pin" placeholder="your pin"><br>
    <input type="submit" valu='Submit'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**my show.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>students <a href="{{url_for('new')}}">Add student</a></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Addr</th>
                <th>Pin</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in students %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.addr }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.pin }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post your directory structure?  I.e., do your html files sit under a 'templates' directory?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where exactly does all this code go wrong?

Comment: no i am new in flask .i couldn't debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

in `new.html` you are sending data to the root path `/` instead of `/new`